# Ionic 4 tabbar PWA on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, tabbar, ionic4

I am building a PWA with Ionic 4, it works perfectly in the browser but when I added it to the home screen to be a standalone PWA, I faced this problem: [problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzDiG.jpg)

There is a space below the tabbar,

and when I added this line to `variables.scss`:

`ion-app {height:100%;}`

another problem appeared:
[problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7pA.jpg)

There is a part of the body is covering the tabbar, on android it works nicely without any problems, the problem is on iOS (iPad and iPhone 7 plus)

What is the problem here? Did anyone face this before? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the SafeArea in iOS since iPhone X. [Read this](https://codeburst.io/making-ionic-cordova-app-compatible-for-iphone-x-c84d62b61aa9), I hope it will help you.

Comment: The problem is not with iPhone X it is with iPhone 7 and iPad